# Drop down field not showing values of existing list items

Tags: infopath, dropdown

I have a SharePoint list which has been configured in InfoPath. Currently there are about 300 entries already. One of the columns - Country - has values for these 300 entries. But when I edit the list item, the Country filed is blank.

This issue started today and the list was working all fine till now. Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

There was the same problem, decided it the following way reconnected the list to DataSource, but before that you have InfoPath not cached data.
Also pay attention to the limit of view list items, that it is not less than 300.

Comment: I figured the issue was caused due to a Form rule. 'Onchange' of another field, the Country field was getting blanked out. This is a peculiar issue because even though onchange was not triggered this was happening. I have disabled that rule itself.